# How to join values of 2 lists in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have below mentioned 2 lists

foo:
'1',
'2',
'3',

bar:
'a',
'b',
'c',

I want to combine the values of 2 list and get the below output in ansible. i tried using map attribute but getting error while using 2 map attributes together.

result:
'1_a'
'2_b'
'3_c'

Comment: Neither the variables *foo* and *bar*, not the expected result ``result: '1_a' '2_b' '3_c'`` are valid [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/). Edit the question and make it [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the lists

```yaml
  foo: ['1', '2', '3']
  bar: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

the expression below

```yaml
  result: "{{ foo|zip(bar)|map('join', '_')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result: [1_a, 2_b, 3_c]
```